# Solving differential equations given conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics

Can anyone help me solving the differential equation: $$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\Psi(t)\rangle=H|\Psi(t)\rangle$$
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_0(t)\\\alpha_1(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\-i&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_0(t)\\\alpha_1(t)\end{pmatrix}$$
Where we have that $$|\Psi(t)\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_0(t)\\\alpha_1(t)\end{pmatrix}$$ and the condition, that
expand the state at time t in the basis $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$, such that
$$|\Psi(t)\rangle=\alpha_0(t)|0\rangle+\alpha_1(t)|1\rangle$$ the Hamiltonian (H) of the system in this basis be given by
$$
H=\omega\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
1 &0 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &-i \\ 
-i &0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and assume that for $t=0$ the state of the system is just given by $\psi(t=0)=\left . \left |   0  \right \rangle\right .$

Can anyone help me solving the equation given by the conditions? I'm not sure how to deal with matrix and complex number solving a differential equation? Hope anyone can help me?

Comment: Your equation looks incorrect, because the units do not match. On the left-hand side of your differential equation, the operator has units of energy, $M\cdot{L^2}/T^2,$ which on the right-hand side, the Hamiltonian is either dimensionless, or has units of angular frequency, and you also wrote that both Hamiltonians are equal, later, despite having different units. The Hamiltonian must have units of energy. So it looks as though the equation should be $$H=\hbar\omega\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=i\hbar\omega\begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\-i&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Yeah I think you are right. But I have to use this to derive a differential equations for $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$, so therefore I have written the equation on that form. But is that wrong?

Comment: Even if you are trying to derive a differential equation, you still must keep the units the same on both sides.

Comment: Oh yeah makes sense. But what would a way to use this Schrödinger's equation in order to derive a differential equations for $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$? Can you help me?

Comment: What you have is the system $$i\hbar\dot{a_0}(t)=\hbar\omega{a_1}(t),$$ $$i\hbar\dot{a_1}(t)=\hbar\omega{a_0}(t).$$ This is obtained via simple matrix multiplication. This can be simplified to $$\dot{a_0}(t)=-i\omega{a_1}(t),$$ $$\dot{a_1}(t)=-i\omega{a_0}(t).$$ The former equation implies $$\ddot{a_0}(t)=-i\omega\dot{a_1}(t),$$ and in conjunction with the latter, this implies $$\ddot{a_0}(t)=-\omega^2a_0(t).$$